# DatePicker MinDate is selectable - Android

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I have set up a `minDate()` to my `DatePicker` view.
Now the problem is that I still can choose from the dates before the minimum date I assigned.

My java:

```
long thirtyDaysInMilliseconds = 2592000000l;
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - thirtyDaysInMilliseconds); // Setting the minimum date
```

My XML:

```
 <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_id" 

    />
```

And a picture to demonstrate:

[image]

See I can still choose the 1 which is not the range of the `minDate()` I assigned(Also 1 - 9 is not in the range and 10 - 13 is in the range).The circle besides it shows it selectable. I want to not be able to click on those. Also i can retrieve information from those "unselected dates
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for my DatePicker that is displayed as a dialog fragment.

I noticed this only happens on lollipop

my solution is NOT perfect but will help prevent a date that is out of range from breaking code but will still be selectable :(

So set your min date and max date on date picker.

```
    if (mMinDate != null) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mMinDate.getTime());
    }

    if (mMaxDate != null) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mMaxDate.getTime());
    }
```

Then in your code where you extract the current date from the picker (in my case it was dialog with an OK button) do this check

```
//Just getting the current date from the date picker
    int day = ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).getDatePicker().getDayOfMonth();
                        int month = ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).getDatePicker().getMonth();
                        int year = ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).getDatePicker().getYear();
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(year, month, day);
                        Date date = calendar.getTime(); //This is what we use to compare with. 


 /** Only do this check on lollipop because the native picker has a bug where the min and max dates are ignored */
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        boolean isDateValid = true; //Start as OK but as we go through our checks this may become false
                        if(mMinDate != null){
                            //Check if date is earlier than min
                            if(date.before(mMinDate)){
                                isDateValid = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if(mMaxDate != null){
                            //Check if date is later than max
                            if(date.after(mMaxDate)){
                                isDateValid = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if(isDateValid){ //if true we can use date, if false do nothing but you can add some else code
                            /** ALL GOOD DATE APPLY CODE GOES HERE */
                        }
                    }else{ //We are not on lollipop so no need for this check
                        /** ALL GOOD DATE APPLY CODE GOES HERE */
                    }
```